# Ubuntu switched from eth0 to eth2 after changing network adapter

Tags: networking, virtualization

I am virtualizing an ubuntu desktop 10.04.
As I had to change the ethernet adapter mac address I got an eth2 network interface in place of eth0.

I'd like to reswitch to eth0. On centos there is a file in which you can edit those things...how can I do the same in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are looking for is probably `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`